# how get the right numpy

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am trying to install bcolz package for python 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.8.
If I use

```
python setup.py install
```

The result is:

```
* Found Cython 0.20.2 package installed.
* Found numpy 1.8.1 package installed.
* Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.
running install
running build
running build_py
....
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bcolz': Permission denied
```

So I tried:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

But now it seemed to look for old numpy

```
* Found Cython 0.20.2 package installed.
.. ERROR:: You need numpy 1.7 or greater to run bcolz!
```

Could someone help me to explain this and show me away to get around? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure they're both using the same Python?  Do `which python` and `sudo which python` return the same result?

Comment: @DSM: Yes, they both point to /usr/bin/python

Comment: install numpy with sudo.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I did. This is the command I used to install numpy: `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" pip install numpy`

Comment: when you run python and `import numpy` what does `numpy.__version__ `show?

Comment: do this command for find the path of your numpy so give me the result 
`python -c 'import os,numpy;print(numpy.__file__)'`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: running python, version of numpy is 1.8.1. However, running sudo python, import numpy gives error: ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: @Kasra: 
Without sudo: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc .
With sudo: 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    ...
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
      from . import multiarray
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: i think you must change the owner of your python installation dir ... because its root ,and any thing that u install like new versin of `numpy` with sudo install in it and the `bcolz` cant access to that directory ... !

Comment: @HuongOrchid you probably needed to compile for `"-arch x86_64"`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I set my python to prefer 32 bits to be able to run MySQLdb. So when I compile numpy for `-arch x86_64`, then import numpy, python gave error for multiarray.so in numpy: `mach-o, but wrong architecture`. Only after installing numpy with `-arch i386`, it works

Comment: I finally got bcolz installed by change the permission of site-packages folder. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not a direct answer to your question, but maybe helpful for all people that start python and face such problems. I would to point on using anaconda for managing python packages. Its much easier and avoids a lot of trouble of that kind.

http://continuum.io/downloads